# Can you open Google Calendar from Sheets and go to a date chosen/clicked in Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have seen quite a few videos with scripts that cleverly link/transfer appointments from Google Sheets To Google calendar

I want something a little easier (I think). I would like to be able to select a date in Sheets, click the date or press a button and have Google Calendar open and go to that date. Is this possible? I guess so if the above can be done but is there a script out there.

I want to be able to choose/click the date and not have to enter it.

Basically I have my own Sheets staff rota and would like to manually duplicate on Calendar (I have reasons I don't want automated as above)

```
20 Mar 2016 : John
21 Mar 2016 : Jane
22 Mar 2016 : Peter
23 Mar 2016 : Chris
```

So I could click e.g. 21 March 2016, and it would open GC and go to that date, either weekly view or whatever.

My Sheet covers a whole year hence the need for a quick link else could manually open GC and just scroll through.

Also, I will look myself a little more but did just wonder if a script can be run from a keyboard shortcut, e.g. Ctrl X  - Excel can assign function keys etc. It would be good for this. For another script I have I have a drawing object ans sue that but not ideal, especially if I want to click a date.
If above is possible and click a date and then the Run Script, will it remember which cell I am/was currently on?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of solved myself. After days looking, I post a question, then looking at something a little different I find 95% solution.

I find that direct HTML link
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc&date=20081101
takes you to the correct month

So I can make up a link with..
="https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc&date="&TEXT(D15,"yyyymmdd")

D15 has my dates already but in wrong format 1 Sep 2017, hence the TEXT bit

This is actually neater than a script as can open from cell next to the date (or anywhere I choose).

However would be nice to tidy up. Ideally like to go to the exact date, this bring up the month. Also is there a way to click the link with ONE click, at the moment you have to click then then click again on the Arrow thing, not great issue but a little fiddly and would just be better.

Comment: I've removed some supplementary questions from this, as they do not belong in answers. They sounded sufficiently different that they should be posted as new questions (with a hyperlink to this question if appropriate). You can retrieve that material in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43045627/revisions) if you need it.